# A Holomorphic Polynomial in $\mathbf C[x,y]$ is a Polynomial in $\mathbf C[z]$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(x,y)\in \mathbf C[x, y]$ be entire (when viewed as a function from $\mathbf C$ to $\mathbf C$ in a natural way).
>   Then there exists a polynomial $P(z)\in \mathbf C[z]$ such that
>   $$
> f(a, b)=P(a+ib)
> $$
>   for all $a,b\in \mathbf R$.

I tried to argue by using Cauchy-Reimann equations and induction on the degree of $f$.

Since $f$ is entire, so is $f_x$, which is also equal to $(1/i)f_y$.
Now $f_x$ is in $\mathbf C[x,y]$, so we may inductively assume that there exists $Q(z)\in \mathbf C[z]$ such that $Q(a, b)=P(a+ ib)$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbf R$.

I am unable to complete the induction.

Can somebody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a different approach. Define the polynomial $g(x)\in\Bbb C[x]$ by $g(x):=f(x,0)$.

Then $f(x,y)-g(x+iy)$ is entire and identically $0$ on $\Bbb R$...

Comment: This is brilliant. No wait. This is brilliance.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, your $f(x,y) =  \sum b_{mn}z^m \bar z^n$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = \sum_{n \ne 0} n b_{mn} z^m \bar z^{n-1}$, so $f$  is $\mathbb{C}$ -differentiable only where $\sum_{n \ne 0} n b_{mn} z^m \bar z^{n-1}=0$.